# Construct a matrix with the required Null Space and Column Space

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Construct a matrix with the required property: Nullspace contains $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and Column space contains $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

I am self studying from G.S's Linear Algebra book and was confused from this question, how do you approach such a question and how do you go about solving it?

Comment: There are several ways to approach this, but it’s hard to guess which one will make the most sense to you without knowing how far you’ve gotten in your studies. Have a look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025318/constructing-a-matrix-given-its-column-space-and-null-space?rq=1) for some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, both the column and null spaces are subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$, so you’re looking for a $2\times2$ matrix. By the Rank-Nullity theorem, this matrix will have rank 1, hence all of its columns are multiples of $(3,1)^T$ (why?). So, try $$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&3\alpha\\1&\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$ $A$’s null space must include $(1,3)^T$, i.e., $A$ must satisfy $$\begin{bmatrix}3&3\alpha\\1&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3+9\alpha \\ 1+3\alpha \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$ I expect you can take it from here. The solution is not unique, of course, since you could just as well have started with $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3\alpha&3\beta\\\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}$$ instead, which would’ve led you to a linear equation relating acceptable values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should really wait a bit longer before doing so in case a better one comes along.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

You want a matrix which represents the linear map given by $(1, 3) \mapsto 0$, $(3, 1) \mapsto (3, 1)$. Note that $\{(1, 3), (3, 1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ so such a map will be uniquely determined.

To write down the formula, note that:

$$(x,y) = \frac{3y - x}8 (1, 3) + \frac{3x-y}8 (3, 1) \mapsto \frac{3x-y}8 (3, 1) = \frac{1}{8}\left(9x-3y, 3x-y\right)$$

So the map is given by $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{1}{8}\left(9x-3y, 3x-y\right)$.

Now just write down its matrix:

$$A = \frac18 \begin{bmatrix} 9 & -3 \\ 3 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Indeed, $A(3, 1) = (3, 1)$ so $(3,1) \in \operatorname{Im} A$, and $A(1, 3) = 0$ so $(1, 3) \in \operatorname{Ker} A$.

Of course, you can drop the $\frac18$, the image and the kernel will remain the same.